# Brackets file not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a slidenav on brackets it was working just fine, now I reopen it and its not working anymore, I see just a blank screen, I've erased part of the code but its all messed up now, what happened? this is the CSS code

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: aqua;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.openbar div{
    height: 5px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.openbar{
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.2em 0 0 1.2em;    
}
.sidenav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: mintcream;
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidenav a{
    color: darkslateblue;
    font-family: gotham;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin: 0 50px;
}
.sidenav a:nth-child(2){
    margin-top: 4em
}
.sidenav .closebtn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    padding:
}
.sidenav a:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: aqua;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Your padding under .sidenav .closebtn is empty and being left open and breaking your css. Give it a value and close it or removing this line should help.

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice that but that wasn't the problem... still not working

Comment: Do you have the html or can you put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: sure https://jsfiddle.net/2gj3jh19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nav got moved into your sidebar. If you move the end div for sidebar back above the nav it should work the way you want it too. https://jsfiddle.net/2gj3jh19/6/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidenav" id="main">
    <a href="#" class="closebtn">X</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">CALL US</a>
    <a href="#">EMAIL</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="openbar">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
```